# How to make position: absolute listen to the parent relative element even if the absolute has margin?

Tags: html, css

How to make child element's width listen to the parent element's width if the child position is absolute( it has also margin-left which moves out the element from parent ) and the parent position is relative.

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

    section{
        width: 50%;
        height: 100px;
        background: gray;
        position: relative;
    }

    div{
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        margin-left: 10%;
        background: red;
        position: absolute;
    }



    </style>
</head>
<body>

<section>
    <div></div>
</section>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: There isn’t any `position` in your “example” …

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I have corrected the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `margin-left:10%` by `left:10%`, set `right:0` to “anchor” the element on the other side of the relative parent as well, and then set `width` to `auto` (resp. remove `width:100%`, then `auto` will be the default).

```css
section {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: gray;
}
div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    right:0;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you should use an overflow.

```
section{
        width: 50%;
        height: 100px;
        background: gray;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

This will stop the child from over running the parent.